# How to run a script before wifi is connected to a network?

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, systemd

I was trying to build a systemd service to run after the networking is up.

/etc/systemd/system/caportal.service

```
[Unit]
Description=captive portal automation

DefaultDependencies=no
After=local-fs.target


[Service]
Type=oneshot

ExecStart=/sbin/wpa_cli -a /home/pi/test.sh -B
ExecStop=/usr/bin/pkill -f /home/pi/test.sh

RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=network.target
```

But this service does not start at reboot. It start when manually started by `sudo systemctl start caportal.service`.

But after reboot, the status information of this service was given below.

```
● caportal.service - captive portal automation
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/caportal.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2019-04-11 10:59:32 UTC; 3min 3s ago
  Process: 287 ExecStart=/sbin/wpa_cli -a /home/pi/test.sh -B (code=exited, status=255)
 Main PID: 287 (code=exited, status=255)

Apr 11 10:59:32 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting captive portal automation...
Apr 11 10:59:32 raspberrypi wpa_cli[287]: Failed to connect to non-global ctrl_ifname: (null)  error: No such file or directory
Apr 11 10:59:32 raspberrypi systemd[1]: caportal.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
Apr 11 10:59:32 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start captive portal automation.
Apr 11 10:59:32 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Unit caportal.service entered failed state.
```

How to start the service at reboot before the network start?

Answer (score 1):

No, the status output says that your script *did* start successfully. However, it ran *too* early: the log shows that wpa_cli *had* been started, but exited because it couldn't connect to wpa_supplicant – which at this stage is not running yet.

The problem is that you're trying to insert the script between two events which the service manager considers as a single unit:

1. You want it to run after wpa_supplicant has started (because wpa_cli wants to connect to it).
2. You want it to run before wpa_supplicant has found and associated with a network.

There's no way you can achieve this with systemd configuration alone.

One of your options is to disable automatic connection but add an *ExecStartPost=* script which tells wpa_supplicant to begin connecting after wpa_cli has successfully started. Alternatively, keep automatic connection, but add an *ExecStartPost=* script which manually triggers the test.sh actions if necessary.

Further problems with your unit:

- *Type=oneshot* tells systemd to expect that this is a short-lived unit that runs and exits, but `wpa_cli -a` obviously isn't that – according to its manual page, it runs as a daemon and needs *Type=simple*.
- *RemainAfterExit=yes* is unnecessary because this isn't an 'oneshot' service. It'll only cause confusion – e.g. if wpa_cmd crashes, the service would still appear "active" even though it isn't running anymore, because this option told it so.
- *DefaultDependencies=no* is unnecessary; that's *way* too early in terms of dependency ordering. Regular wpa_supplicant doesn't have this, so it's not needed here either; a simple *Before=* or *After=* is usually enough.

Comment: Thanks @grawity. Can I start the script after wpa_supplicant.service? Also How to view the order in which systemd process each service?

Comment: Sure, `[Unit] After=wpa_supplicant.service`. But you can't guarantee that it'll run before or after wpa_supplicant has done something-or-other, only that it'll run after it has "started". Use `systemctl list-dependencies --after`, `--before`, and maybe `systemd-analyze dot | dot -Tx11`?

Comment: yeah, I have already tried that `After=wpa_supplicant.service`. But it wasn't working. Now it shows the service as inactive

Comment: `systemctl list-dependencies --after`, this list not showing wpa_supplicant.service`

Comment: Did you tell it to list caportal.service?

Comment: Yeah now i got the list, but the list shows that `local-fs.target ` is run after `wpa_supplicant.service`. Then why wpa_cli is got error?

Comment: why the service is showing `inactive` and Process is showing `success`. What does it mean? But `ps` command shows `test.sh` is not running.